# mysql query table values that did change

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       number     |        rel       |        val       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         34       |        NULL      |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         35       |         1        |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         36       |         1        |         b        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         37       |        NULL      |         c        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          5          |         38       |         4        |         d        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          6          |         39       |         4        |         c        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

In my real table there is no rel = null. I just added it to understand the structure.

With `rel` I create a relationship to another `id` of the same table.

How can I query all rows, where `val` is not equal (did change).
E.g.:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       number     |        rel       |        val       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         36       |         1        |         b        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          5          |         38       |         4        |         d        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: _where val is not equal _ compared to what?

Comment: that's maybe the issue. Where val is not equal to the related row with the id = rel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM nooneevernamestheirtableinsqlquestions AS t1
JOIN nooneevernamestheirtableinsqlquestions AS t2
  ON t1.rel = t2.id AND t1.val <> t2.val
```

Comment: thank you. did not know to add a second criteria to the on part. The code is only working for `where t2.val IS NOT NULL`. This is weird, because there is no value NULL in my objects table. yes, it is called objects ;)

Comment: Read about MySQL's [NULL-safe comparison operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

Answer (score 1):

As you only want to show only one row per rel
You can use this, which will select the highest id

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `number` INTEGER,
>   `rel` VARCHAR(4),
>   `val` VARCHAR(1)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`ID`, `number`, `rel`, `val`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '34', 'NULL', 'a'),
>   ('2', '35', '1', 'a'),
>   ('3', '36', '1', 'b'),
>   ('4', '37', 'NULL', 'c'),
>   ('5', '38', '4', 'd'),
>   ('6', '39', '4', 'c');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t1.`ID`, t1.`number`, t1.`rel`, t1.`val` 
> FROM table1 t1
> INNER JOIN table1 t2 
> ON t1.rel = t2.rel 
>     AND t1.val <> t2.val
>     AND t1.ID > t2.ID
> WHERE t1.rel > 0
>     AND t2.rel > 0
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | number | rel | val
> -: | -----: | :-- | :--
>  3 |     36 | 1   | b  
>  6 |     39 | 4   | c
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28d95f5121f4324885f9bec5a537d4d4)*

If you got more changes and you want only 1 row

you can slect the max for examl of number

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `number` INTEGER,
>   `rel` VARCHAR(4),
>   `val` VARCHAR(1)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`ID`, `number`, `rel`, `val`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '34', 'NULL', 'a'),
>   ('2', '35', '1', 'a'),
>   ('3', '36', '1', 'b'),
>   ('4', '37', 'NULL', 'c'),
>   ('5', '38', '4', 'd'),
>   ('6', '39', '4', 'c'),
>   ('7', '40', '4', 'r');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT t1.`ID`, t1.`number`, t1.`rel`, t1.`val` 
> FROM table1 t1
> INNER JOIN table1 t2 
> ON t1.rel = t2.rel 
>     AND t1.val <> t2.val
>     AND t1.ID > t2.ID
> INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(number) max_num, `rel` FROM table1 GROUP BY rel) t3   ON  t1.rel = t3.rel AND t1.number = t3.max_num
> WHERE t1.rel > 0
>     AND t2.rel > 0
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | number | rel | val
> -: | -----: | :-- | :--
>  3 |     36 | 1   | b  
>  7 |     40 | 4   | r
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2684cc2ce0bfeabf0446f10ec9830c14)*